# 'Select next occurrence' keyboard shortcut in jsfiddle (chrome mac)

Tags: jsfiddle

Just curious if you can **select next occurrence** in the jsfiddle editor using a keyboard shortcut?

In sublime it would be `cmd + D` and in phpStorm it would be `ctrl + G`.

Jsfiddle in chrome mac supports other similar editor shortcuts such as `cmd + [` and `cmd + /`, but I can't find any cheatsheets or jsfiddle docs that mention these shortcuts and what they do.

Does anyone know a list of all available jsfiddle editor shortcuts?

Thanks